# What does 'channelling your inner cupcakke' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

This was from a meme group on Facebook. I commented on a post entitled "how many is your battery percentage" where there were options. Each option was meant to be a weapon to defend myself from Michael Myers. Then a guy replied to my comment. He wrote:

> You're just channelling your inner cupcakke.

Thus doesn't make any sense, in my view. I think, did he mean to say **[cupcake](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cupcakes&amp=true&page=6)** instead of **[cupcakke](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm=CupcakKe&amp=true)**? Isn't it some kind of dessert?

I also googled the term channelling your inner and I came up with [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/channeling-my-inner.3492837/). Still don't understand!

Comment: Cupcakke is an over-the-top sexual rap artist. If this wasn't a typo, then that guy was saying you're being highly sexual. So, either your comment was sexual, or he sees a double entendre in it and was making a joke about it.

Comment: It would help if you provided some context -- what did you say in the post that they responded to?

Comment: Taking a guess:  Was your battery percentage at 69?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the links on that forum thread you found, **to channel** here [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/channel#Etymology_2):

> 4. (*transitive*) To follow as a model, especially in a performance.
>    *He was trying to **channel** President Reagan, but the audience wasn't buying it.*
>    *When it is my turn to sing karaoke, I am going to **channel** Ray Charles.*

The phrase "channel your inner [noun]" is a metaphor, as if there is some "hidden" or "inner" [noun] that you can *channel*, that is, allow to be expressed more so than it usually would be. For example, if you want to cook a nice meal for your partner, you might "channel your inner chef" and allow that part of you which enjoys cooking good food to be expressed. If you want to pump yourself up before playing in a football game you might "channel your inner warrior."

In this context I would definitely say that the person meant to type "You're just channeling your inner **cupcake**." A cupcake, literally, is a sweet pastry food; by extension it can be [used as an insult](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cupcake#Noun):

> 3. (*slang*) A weak or effeminate man. [synonyms: cockney, pansy, sissy]

I'm not sure what exactly you said that would cause him to respond like that, but presumably it was not sufficiently "macho."

Comment: I'm not familiar with the frachise that Michael Myers came from, but it also seems possible that there's a character called "Cupcake" in them that their response was reminiscent of.

Comment: "channelling *your inner*" cannot follow this meaning. It is closer to meaning 3: "To serve as a medium for [a spirit]"

Comment: @nick012000: For reference, the character of Michael Myers is from the horror movie franchise *Halloween*. (That said, I have no idea whether there's anyone named "Cupcake" in the franchise...)

Comment: @V2Blast Unless they were talking about Canadian actor/comedian *Mike* Myers, best known as Austin Powers and Shrek.  Without context, it's hard to say...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I mean, we do have context in the original post: "a weapon to defend myself from Michael Myers." To me, that pretty strongly indicates that it's about the killer character from a horror movie – not an *actor* who mostly appears in comedy films.

Comment: @V2Blast Have you seen *The Cat in the Hat*?  You might want a weapon for that one...

Comment: There's definitely no character named "Cupcake" in any of the *Halloween* movies.